# Python асинхронные запросы через ZeroMQ

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio, zeromq

Есть блокирующий метод, который должен c помощью либы ZeroMQ сделать несколько асинхронных запросов каждому слушателям из списка, после отправки сообщения, дождаться первого ответа от любого из..., после получения первого же ответа нужно реджектнуть остальные соединения и вернуть полученное сообщение.

Как всё это дело можно навернуть на asyncio?

На данный момент реализован только функционал запрос-ответа.

```
import zmq

socket = None
message = None
id = 500
req_timeout_ms = 1500
request = b'test data'
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, id)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, req_timeout_ms)
socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:7654')
socket.send_multipart([request])
message = socket.recv()
print(message)
```

Comment: `socket = None` ... `socket.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, id)` что-то я сомневаюсь что код работает

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл добавить строчку

Comment: И небольшое уточнение, мне даже подойдёт вариант, like a javascript style, с калбэками. Не обязательно что бы сам метод что-то возвращал.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает `zmq.asyncio` ? Начиная с версии 15 можно использовать асинхронный контекст для zmq.

Comment: Меня устроит любой вариант, но нигде не смог найти как одновременно отправить несколько запросов, клиент ведь не будет ждать, пока по таймауту у него до 10ого запроса дойдёт.
Во всех доках написаны примеры с, по сути, синхронным выполнением.
Тема очень сложная, и в документациях ничего внятного нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде

```
listeners = [...]
ctx = zmq.asyncio.Context()

async def send(listener):
    ...
    message = await socket.recv()
    ...


finished, unfinished = loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.wait([send(i) for i in listeners],
                 return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED))

for task in unfinished:
    task.cancel()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, наконец-то разобрался как это всё работает!)